# list of checkboxes in angular and ng-repeat.. All checkboxes check together? how to save check separately?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm creating a to-do list app with angular, pretty simple, but I am having an issue with the checkboxes--- If I click one check box, they all get checked... How can I separate it so it only checks one at a time and then checks to save checked/unchecked boxes?

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="HomeController as vm"
ng-cloak>
    <input type="text" placeholder="To do..."
    ng-model="vm.myTask">
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.submitTask()">Submit</button>
    </br>

    <label ng-repeat="Task in vm.myTasks">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{Task}}"
            ng-model="vm.taskList">{{Task}}</li>
        </ul>
    </label>
```

homeController.js

```
//task array
var myTasks = [];

class HomeController {



//submit task from input value
submitTask(){
//push new task into array
  myTasks.push(this.myTask);

}
constructor(myTask){
this.myTasks = myTasks;
}



}

angular.module("myapp").controller("HomeController", HomeController);
```

Comment: constructor argument says `myTask` and you're assigning `myTasks` <-- extra **s** to `this.myTasks`  **s** is confusing!

Comment: I know, thats the only way I could get it to work. myTasks is the array that stores myTask

Comment: If you need to get checkbox separete two option: 1) use variable boolean in you object from you myTasks. 2) use ng-init in you input. And use ng-change for send value from your model ng-init to your controller

Comment: could you give me an example of the second option? I'm looking through the documentation but i'm not really comprehending how it works exactly

Comment: @karmadreamwalker Could you please provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: I just tried to, but I cant get js fiddle to work with the angular... because it only lets me have one js file I think? so there isn't anywhere for my app.js file?

Comment: Just add your app.js code into the javascript area. You dont need it to be in an external app.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to push the checked tasks in an array and manipulate this array based on checking/unchecking of checkbox.

**JS**

```
constructor(myTask,checkedTask){
this.myTasks = myTasks;
this.checkedTask = checkedTask;
}

check(task,indx){
  var index = checkedTask.indexOf(task);
        if (index > -1)
            checkedTask.splice(index, 1);
            else
            checkedTask.push(task);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{Task}}"
                  ng-click="vm.check(Task,$index)" ng-checked="vm.checkedTask.indexOf(Task)>-1">{{Task}}
   </li>
```

**Working Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/cDrWUteexBgmAug3Pj2S?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer it a bit easier. Change your task to be an object with a name and checked-property. Bind the checkbox to the checked property of your task. Done.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="HomeController as vm"
ng-cloak>
    <input type="text" placeholder="To do..."
    ng-model="vm.myTask">
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.submitTask()">Submit</button>
    <br>

    <label ng-repeat="task in vm.myTasks"> <!-- lowercase task -->
        <ul>
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{task.name}}" ng-model="task.checked">{{task.name}}</li> <!-- task is now an object, not only a string, so we access the properties name and checked -->
        </ul>
    </label>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

var myTasks = [];

class HomeController {



//submit task from input value
submitTask(){
//push new task into array
  myTasks.push({name: this.myTask, checked: false}); //create new object and push it into the array

}
constructor(myTask,checkedTask){
this.myTasks = myTasks;
}

}

app.controller("HomeController", HomeController);
```

Working plunker (based on Vivz plunker):
https://plnkr.co/edit/CUPw165TQGiLusJEWqkr?p=preview